# Does zero free current entail zero $\vec H$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

There are two kinds of magnetic fields (different authors give them different names), $\vec B $ and $\vec H$ which are related by the equation $$ \vec B = \mu_o (\vec H + \vec M)$$ where $\vec M$ is the magnetization.

Ampere's law for free currents states $$\oint_C \vec H \cdot d\vec l = I_{free} $$

This is my question: does zero free current entail zero $\vec H$?

My argument for that is this: since the contour integral of $\vec H$ is zero for all arbitrary curves C in a region of zero free current, $\vec H$ is necessarily zero. However this may not be a mathematically correct argument...

Comment: Your argument concerning the vanishing of $\vec{H}$ could be applied to any vector with zero curl.  In particular, you could use the same logic to prove that the electric field vanished everywhere in space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your argument is completely flawed.

Consider a uniform H-field. The closed line integral of this field around any loop is zero - and there must be no free current through the loop. Hence there is no free current, yet the H-field is non-zero.

You might be better off thinking about this in terms of free current density.

In this case we can say
$$\nabla \times {\bf H} = {\bf J},$$
so that a zero free current density just means that the H-field has zero curl at that point, nothing more than that.

Comment: oh, i didn't think of that... so given a system with only bound current (zero free current everywhere), $\vec H$ can still be nonzero? But why do some problems end up with $\vec B = \mu_o \vec M$?

Comment: @quarkleptonboson You'd have to be specific. In LIH media, what you suggest implies $\vec{H}=\vec{M}/\mu_r$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with your argument.
Don’t forget $\vec H$ and $\mathrm d\vec l$ are vectors!
$\vec H\cdot\mathrm d\vec l$ is a "dot product",
so the $\oint$ sum the same direction of $\vec H\cdot\mathrm d\vec l$,
Which means if $\vec H$ is a constant
you can take it out the $\int$
and it becomes $\vec H \oint\mathrm d l$ (here $\mathrm dl$ is scalar since they are in the same direction).
So if the free current is zero,
$\vec H$ must be zero!

Answer (score 0):

For example, if only permanent magnets exist, the free current ($\bf{J}_{\text{free}}$) is zero, but both $\bf{B}$ and $\bf{H}$ are not zero.